# Dynamically resize TableViewController Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield, cell

In my project I have a `SignUpViewController` which looks like this:

[image]

All the `textFields` are custom-`cells` within a `tableViewController`.

**`TableView:`**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 7
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // 1st cell -> email textfield
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SignUpEmailCell", for: indexPath) as! SignUpEmailCell
        return cell
    // 2nd cell -> anzeigename
    }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SignUpAnzeigeName", for: indexPath) as! SignUpAnzeigeName
        return cell
    // 3rd cell -> Wishlist-Handle
    }else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SignUpHandleCell", for: indexPath) as! SignUpHandleCell
        return cell
    // 4th cell -> passwort textfield
    }else if indexPath.row == 3 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SignUpPasswordCell", for: indexPath) as! SignUpPasswordCell
        return cell
    // 5th cell -> repeat password textfield
    }else if indexPath.row == 4 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SignUpPasswordRepeatCell", for: indexPath) as! SignUpPasswordRepeatCell
        return cell
    // 6th cell -> document label
    }else if indexPath.row == 5 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SignUpDocumentCell", for: indexPath) as! SignUpDocumentCell
        return cell
    }
    // last cell -> signUpButton
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SignUpButtonCell", for: indexPath) as! SignUpButtonCell
    return cell
}
```

**`Password-Cell`:**  (basic structure is the same for every cell)

```
    class SignUpPasswordCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    public static let reuseID = "SignUpPasswordCell"
    
    lazy var eyeButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(eyeButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        v.setImage(UIImage(named: "eyeOpen"), for: .normal)
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
    
    lazy var passwordTextField: CustomTextField = {
        let v = CustomTextField()
        v.borderActiveColor = .white
        v.borderInactiveColor = .white
        v.textColor = .white
        v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 17)
        v.placeholder = "Passwort"
        v.placeholderColor = .white
        v.placeholderFontScale = 0.8
        v.minimumFontSize = 13
        v.borderStyle = .line
        v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SignUpPasswordCell.passwordTextFieldDidChange(_:)),for: .editingChanged)
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")}

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        passwordTextField.delegate = self
        
        eyeButton.isHidden = true
        passwordTextField.textContentType = .newPassword
        passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry.toggle()
        
        setupViews()
    }
    
    func setupViews(){
        contentView.addSubview(passwordTextField)
        contentView.addSubview(eyeButton)
        
        passwordTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        passwordTextField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        passwordTextField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
        
        eyeButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        eyeButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    }

    var check = true
    @objc func eyeButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        check = !check
        
        if check == true {
            eyeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "eyeOpen"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            eyeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "eyeClosed"), for: .normal)
        }
        passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry.toggle()

            if let existingText = passwordTextField.text, passwordTextField.isSecureTextEntry {
                /* When toggling to secure text, all text will be purged if the user
                 continues typing unless we intervene. This is prevented by first
                 deleting the existing text and then recovering the original text. */
                passwordTextField.deleteBackward()

                if let textRange = passwordTextField.textRange(from: passwordTextField.beginningOfDocument, to: passwordTextField.endOfDocument) {
                    passwordTextField.replace(textRange, withText: existingText)
                }
            }
        
            /* Reset the selected text range since the cursor can end up in the wrong
             position after a toggle because the text might vary in width */
            if let existingSelectedTextRange = passwordTextField.selectedTextRange {
                passwordTextField.selectedTextRange = nil
                passwordTextField.selectedTextRange = existingSelectedTextRange
            }
    }
    
    @objc func passwordTextFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
            if textField.text == "" {
                self.eyeButton.isHidden = true
            }else {
                self.eyeButton.isHidden = false
            }
        
    }
}
```

**Problem:**

I would like to be able to show some extra information on some `textFields` **when selected**.
For example: When `passwordTextField` is editing I would like to show the password requirements right below the textfield. But the extra information should only be displayed while editing or after editing. When the `ViewController` is being displayed at first it should still look like the picture above.

I hope my problem is clear and I am grateful for every help.

Comment: I dont know, Why are you going with tableview to registration..Its hard to handle, u will face issues while scrolling

Comment: The reason why I am going with a `tableView` is so its displayble on every phone size

Comment: my suggestion use stackview with scrollview

Comment: @karthikeyan could you have a look at my latest question? I tried it with a stackview and scrollview